# O365 smtp as relay implementation

Tags: python-3.x, email, relay

I am using the below lines of code to send an email but I get the error as 'smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful' . This must be due to MFA. what can I do to authenticate?

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp.office365.com"
sender_email = "myemail@companycom"
receiver_email = "myemail@companycom"
password = input("Type your password and press enter:")
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to manage the app password in your account or request for service accounts to your admin which doesn't have MFA.